# Virtual Box OS stuck with blank screen

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to run Linux OS on my Windows machine as guest OS. To make it run, I have installed Oracle Virtual Box and Ubuntu ISO file. And I have configured it as follows:

Ubuntu version: ubuntu-18.04.2 
Virtual Box version: VirtualBox-6.0.10

Allocated RAM : 4GB/8GB 
Allocated HDD : 10GB

Settings: 
Hyper-V : Disabled 
3D Acceleration: Unchecked

Problem: 
When I start the guest OS, it shows the screen as following and nothing happen, it stuck till you kill it forcefully!

[image]

I checked the logs and it goes as follows,

```
00:00:09.445290 AIOMgr: Async flushes not supported
00:00:09.445380 PcBios: SATA LUN#0 LCHS=1024/255/63
00:00:09.445416 APIC: fPostedIntrsEnabled=false fVirtApicRegsEnabled=false fSupportsTscDeadline=false
00:00:09.445429 TMR3UtcNow: nsNow=1 563 564 355 785 531 700 nsPrev=0 -> cNsDelta=1 563 564 355 785 531 700 (offLag=0 offVirtualSync=0 offVirtualSyncGivenUp=0, NowAgain=1 563 564 355 785 531 700)
00:00:09.445452 VMEmt: Halt method global1 (5)
00:00:09.445475 VMEmt: HaltedGlobal1 config: cNsSpinBlockThresholdCfg=50000
00:00:09.445483 Changing the VM state from 'CREATING' to 'CREATED'
00:00:09.447677 Changing the VM state from 'CREATED' to 'POWERING_ON'
00:00:09.447745 AIOMgr: Endpoints without assigned bandwidth groups:
00:00:09.447757 AIOMgr:     E:\Divyang\ubuntuVM\ubuntu\ubuntu.vdi
00:00:09.447967 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_ON' to 'RUNNING'
00:00:09.447998 Console: Machine state changed to 'Running'
00:00:09.457150 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: VirtualBox 6.0.10
00:00:09.457529 PCI: Setting up resources and interrupts
00:00:09.477694 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:09.527703 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:09.545641 VMMDev: Guest Log: CPUID EDX: 0x178bfbff
00:00:09.546833 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: RESET, DevSel=0 AIOIf=0 CmdIf0=0x00 (-1 usec ago) CmdIf1=0x00 (-1 usec ago)
00:00:09.546961 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: finished processing RESET
00:00:09.608509 AHCI#0: Reset the HBA
00:00:09.608539 VD#0: Cancelling all active requests
00:00:09.609682 AHCI#0: Port 0 reset
00:00:09.609821 VD#0: Cancelling all active requests
00:00:09.615063 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: AHCI 0-P#0: PCHS=16383/16/63 LCHS=1024/255/63 0x0000000001400000 sectors
00:00:09.633141 PIT: mode=2 count=0x48d3 (18643) - 64.00 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:09.635158 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000e610000 w=640 h=480 bpp=32 cbLine=0xA00 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:09.949270 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 800x600
00:00:09.949321 VMMDev: SetVideoModeHint: Got a video mode hint (800x600x32)@(0x0),(1;0) at 0
00:00:09.959741 GUI: 2D video acceleration is disabled
00:00:09.959765 GUI: HID LEDs sync is enabled
00:00:10.001578 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:00:12.105706 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000e610000 w=640 h=480 bpp=0 cbLine=0x280 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:12.127552 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:12.179199 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:12.181798 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=1, bootseq=0231
00:00:12.183508 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot from Floppy 0 failed
00:00:12.185912 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=2, bootseq=0023
00:00:12.189866 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from CD-ROM...
00:00:12.439376 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000e610000 w=640 h=480 bpp=16 cbLine=0x500 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:07:32.244300 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={a7c88b82-2330-44e3-b247-1421a018f9c1} aComponent={KeyboardWrap} aText={Could not send all scan codes to the virtual keyboard (VERR_PDM_NO_QUEUE_ITEMS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-2807
00:07:32.368976 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={a7c88b82-2330-44e3-b247-1421a018f9c1} aComponent={KeyboardWrap} aText={Could not send all scan codes to the virtual keyboard (VERR_PDM_NO_QUEUE_ITEMS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-2807
00:07:32.488736 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={a7c88b82-2330-44e3-b247-1421a018f9c1} aComponent={KeyboardWrap} aText={Could not send all scan codes to the virtual keyboard (VERR_PDM_NO_QUEUE_ITEMS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-2807
00:07:32.594988 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={a7c88b82-2330-44e3-b247-1421a018f9c1} aComponent={KeyboardWrap} aText={Could not send all scan codes to the virtual keyboard (VERR_PDM_NO_QUEUE_ITEMS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-2807
00:07:32.682085 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={a7c88b82-2330-44e3-b247-1421a018f9c1} aComponent={KeyboardWrap} aText={Could not send all scan codes to the virtual keyboard (VERR_PDM_NO_QUEUE_ITEMS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-2807
00:07:32.742048 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={a7c88b82-2330-44e3-b247-1421a018f9c1} aComponent={KeyboardWrap} aText={Could not send all scan codes to the virtual keyboard (VERR_PDM_NO_QUEUE_ITEMS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-2807
00:07:32.834937 ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005) aIID={a7c88b82-2330-44e3-b247-1421a018f9c1} aComponent={KeyboardWrap} aText={Could not send all scan codes to the virtual keyboard (VERR_PDM_NO_QUEUE_ITEMS)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=-2807
```

Not sure if missing some configuration or machine has not enough resources to load this external OS.

System Configuration:

OS: Win10 pro. 
Processor: i3-7020U@2.30GHz 
RAM: 8GB

Comment: Why is the VM trying to boot from Floppy and CD-ROM but not from hard disk? Is the virtual hard disk missing? If you think RAM may be a problem, you could set it to 2GB which enough for Linux, and ensure the VM has 2 CPUs (or one CPU with 2 threads).

Comment: I see, but not sure about the *why*! and I have no idea if there any additional configuration is missing.

Comment: Does checksum match the downloaded version?  The error `VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005)` usually appears with corrupted download.

Comment: It might also be that the hard disk is too small with only 10GB. I suggest creating it as much much bigger, but not pre-allocated, so it only uses as much space as required.

Comment: Added with 100GB, but the issue is still there..@harrymc

Comment: Just to check if something went wrong with your installation, have you tried runing Ubuntu live from CD to see if the same happens? 
Do you have another VM that runs fine in your Desktop or this is the first one?

Comment: @Ronaldo, using the same setup, I'm able to run guest OS my office machine!

Comment: I suggest uninstalling and re-installing VirtualBox.

Comment: @harrymc, thanks, already done several times! let me ask you one question.. if the machine doesn't have genuine OS creates a problem?

Comment: I don't think VirtualBox cares, but Windows might be in an unknown state. Re-installing Windows might solve the problem, if the problem cannot be analyzed.

Comment: @harrymc, okie, thanks! I will check and update here if that would solve the issue.

Comment: @Div - have you tried [vmware player](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/15_0) as virtual box gave me nothing but problems from day 1. VMPlayer worked on day 1 so may be worth a try

Comment: This is ubuntu's splash screen prompt, did you try to press tab key?

If the keyboard works in VM, then the tab key will prompt language selection for installation.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

- Press Win + R
- type OptionalFeatures
- press Enter
- Make sure Hyper-V is turned off.  Reboot is required if you just turned it off.

Answer (score 0):

Many things can cause this issue doing these might solve the issue

1. Enable VT-x on your BIOS
2. Disable Hyper-V
3. Give your VM enough RAM and CPU cores (2GB RAM and 2 CPU cores)
4. Check your download hash with ubuntu's one